# Pc slower after upgrade

Tags: windows-10

We upgraded the old Pc of my friend to:

```
CPU: Intel Core i5-12400F 12. Gen
RAM: 32G DDR4 3200 Mhz Ram
Mainboard: B660 Gaming X
GPU: RX590 (getting upgrade soon)
SSD: Contains Windows from old Pc
```

After turning on, Windows Defender and Updater take around 35% of CPU. Navigating through the settings takes a long time (Opening the Windows updates takes around 30 seconds). The SSD isn't under load. The Pc has also no activation(lost ist due to upgrading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this first :

- Run the Event Viewer and check for relevant error messages
- Install and run the
  [Intel Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html)
  to check for driver updates

Some general causes are:

- The cooler isn’t installed properly and the CPU overheats.
- The RAM isn’t installed properly or you are getting RAM errors
- The power jacks aren’t connected properly : the 24-pin motherboard
  and 8 pin CPU connector
- Wrong drivers are causing issues
- Your motherboard needs a BIOS update to support the new CPU
- The cooler isn’t sufficient for the new CPU and it overheats
- The Case doesn’t have sufficient air-flow causing high temperatures.